# Search the formula content in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: search, google-apps-script, google-sheets, formula, formulas

What I mean in the title is if I want to looking for just only the part of formula's word such as `=ArrayFormula(` in one hit from the menu bar like **Search > Formula**.

Comment: Not sure what your issue is, you can specify to search formulas' contents in the search dialogue.

Comment: Oh my God thank you It's so useful for me I have just know this. Thanks again!

Comment: @halfer I posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> the search dialog appears

[image]

---

Clicking on the three dots makes a dialog appear.
By default  formulas' contents are not searched
[image]

---

Ticking "Also Search within Formulae" will change the display of all cells containing formulae and search those too.
[image]